# Terraform - dynamic cloud-config groups with optional members in template

Tags: terraform

I was trying to create a dynamic cloud-config files using `templatefile(file, vars)`. In my template I invoke the `jsonencode(var)` function in order to render valid yaml. As a mre :

```
#cloud-init
${jsonencode({
  "groups": [ for g in groups : 
     {
       g.name
     }
  ],
  "users": [ for u in users : 
     {
       "name": u.name,
       "gecos": u.gecos,
       "homedir": u.homedir,
     }
})}
```

```
locals {
    json-user-data = templatefile(
        "${path.module}/templates/cloud-init.tpl", 
        {
          groups = var.groups,
          users = var.users
        }
}
```

What I'd like to obtain is something like :

```
groups:
  - ubuntu: [root,sys]
  - cloud-users
```

Where the groups member attribute is optional. I'm having a hard time achiving the result also because Terraform does not like mixed objects. Is there a way to achive something similar?

Thanks for helping, and let me know how to improve my question.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to do? You have `jsonencode`, but your output is in yaml?

Comment: @Marcin I think i've solved it using empty lists allowing to fake the optional argument. json is valid yaml but not vice versa. Ill post my answer if I solve it.